# coin tosses that change their possibilities according to the previous toss

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let's say I have a coin that when tossed has a probability of 50% getting heads, and 50% getting tails. But for the next toss, the side that "won" gets half the chances that the side that "lost" had, so for example, if heads "won", in the next toss the probability will be 75% for heads and 25% for tails. According to this, how do I calculate the possibilities of things like: In ten iterations, what is the possibility that heads will be picked exactly in 7 of those (or even at least in 7 of those)? And how do I calculate a more general case where the probability in the start is not 50-50, but can be 70-30, 20-80, 5-95, and so on?

Comment: You can work recursively.  This is fine for a small number of trials (and $10$ is certainly small) but of course it gets cumbersome if you wanted a large number of trials.

Comment: Note:  one thing that makes the computation especially bad is that the process does not "commute".  That is to say, if you first throw $H$ and then $T$ the probability of Heads, $p_H$,  goes first to $.75$ and then to $.375$ so just knowing how many Heads you have thrown doesn't tell you $p_H$, you need to know the order.  Thus, if you are tracking states, you need enough states to record the full order.  Of course, it is very easy to just sample the process if you don't mind an approximate result.

Comment: Note:  in practice $p_H$ tends to $0$ or $1$ very quickly, which makes approximate methods quite accurate.

Comment: Where does this problem come from ?

Comment: It just something I thought about. There is no another origin that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Code a Heads with $1$ and a Tails with $0$.
Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be (dependent) Bernoulli random variables modeling the tosses.
Say that initially $P(X_1=1)=p$.
The conditional distribution of $X_n$ given the past is as follows:

$$X_n|(X_{n-1}=e_{n-1},\ldots ,X_1=e_1) \sim \text{Bernoulli}\Big(\frac 1{2^{n-1}}(p+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^{k-1}e_k)\Big),$$
and this is easily shown via induction.

This essentially gives  you the joint distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ which is enough to compute any of the coveted probabilities.

For instance, by the multiplication rule,
$$\begin{aligned}
P(\sum_{k=1}^{10} X_k = 7)
= \sum_{\substack{(e_1,\ldots,e_{10})\in \{0,1\}^{10}\\e_1+\ldots+e_{10}=7}}
P(X_n=e_{10}|X_{9}=e_{9},\ldots ,X_1=e_1)\times\ldots\times P(X_1=e_1)
\end{aligned}
$$
and this can be computed in closed form, or implemented on a computer.